# simple regex to remove _ and 0

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for an regex that converts the following strings (string => result):

```
_0001 => 1
_0001r => 1r
_0021v-s001r => 21v-s1r
_0000_0001r => 1r
```

It should essentially remove the `_` and all zeros.

My attempt is: `/[^_0]/`
but for some reason it doesn't work:

https://regex101.com/r/4CWo9S/3

Comment: Remove negation `^`

Comment: remove the `^` -> `[_0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I assume you mean `/[_0]/` the `^` would negate the character class.

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with regex?
It's a simple str_replace that is needed.

```
$str = "_0001 => 1
_0001r => 1r
_0021v-s001r => 21v-s1r
_0000_0001r => 1r";

echo str_replace(["0","_"], "", $str);
```

output:

```
1 => 1
1r => 1r
21v-s1r => 21v-s1r
1r => 1r
```

https://3v4l.org/BrL1M

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're negating the search with the ^ token. You need just to search for `/[_0]/` and replace with "".